# Subset $V$ Lebesgue measurable, but not Borel measurable

Tags: lebesgue-measure, borel-sets, cantor-set, borel-measures

Define the function $g: [0, 1] \rightarrow [0, 1]$ with $$g(y) := \inf\{x \in [0, 1] : f(x) = y\},$$ where $f$ is the Cantor function.

Now let $V \subset [0, 1]$ be a set that is not Lebesgue measurable. Show that $g(V)$ is Lebesgue measurable, but not Borel measurable.

I managed to do answer the first part, but I'm struggling with proving that it's not Borel measurable. Help would be appreciated!

Comment: $V$ is any non-measurable set  or some specific (like Vitali?)

Comment: There wasn't anything more specific stated, $V$ is supposed to be any non-measurable set.

Comment: Maybe https://www.math3ma.com/blog/lebesgue-but-not-borel